# Java: how to check the content of a php script output?

Tags: java, php, inputstream

sorry for the stupid question but my knowledge of java net is terrible.
BAsically in my android application a call many php scripts to get data from a mysql db.
These data are returned in json format and i use Google json library to parse them.
Everything works fine but know in each php page i have to add a test. It the test is successfull, then the script continues and returns the json file, but if the test fails, the script return the string "false", or the value false (that's up to me) and my application instead of showing data has to redirect the user to a login page.

The code is the following:

```
        URL url = new URL(Costanti.IP_SERVER+"myApps.php"+"?userId="+this.userId);
        try 
        {

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (status >= 200 && status <= 299)
            {
                Reader r = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
                Applicazioni dati = new Applicazioni();
                try 
                {

                    dati = gsonReader.fromJson(r, Applicazioni.class);

                    return dati;
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Ho fallito a prendere i dati");
                    Log.e("JSON_Parser",e.toString());

                }
            }   
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Ho fallito la connnection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So basically i use this google library to read the json file inside the imputStreamReader and fill the Applicazioni object with my data.

How can i check if the content of the imputStreamReader is the string "false" or the boolean false and if it's different parse it with the json library????

In the php at the end i do 
echo json_encode($applicazione);
in one case or
echo "false" in the other case
Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(in));
String result = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next(); // this reads the whole
                                                    // script output in a string
if(result.equals("false"))
 handle the false value...
else
  dati = gsonReader.fromJson(result, Applicazioni.class);
```

Comment: Tnx, but can i use scanner also with my Reader r = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
in my code?? cause i use an openConnection to get a HttpURLConnection object instead of openStream(); can you explain me the difference pls :)

Comment: Yeah I suppose you can wrap the conn.getInputStream() inside the scanner and probably get the same result. You'd have to try though, I never used HttpURLConnection before so I can't be sure. It should be pretty quick to test.

Answer (score 1):

You can json encode the false result also like ["result"=>"false"] from PHP, This way you can always JSON decode in your Java program, and then look for result value.

You can put the result value in both cases in the output.

Comment: The problem is that the google json parser asks for the output to be properly formatted.....for example in case the test is succesfull in php i have to create a json output conformed to the class Applicazion....same fields name, same structure ecc....otherwise the parsing fails.......so if i json encode "false" the parsing on the java side will fail theowing an error exception.....

Comment: You can add the result field to your Applicazion class. Then in failure case not fill anything in it except the result. GSON library from Google handles nulls gracefully. So if the fields are empty they will be null in the output object.